# Making copy of a DOM element

Tags: javascript, dom

JSfiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/bryanh210/j8yz2sep/3/

I currently have the following code:

```
const blockMenuEl = document.getElementById('block-menu');
const originalHTML = blockMenuEl.innerHTML;
const display = (arr) => {
  if(arr.length === blocks.length) {
    blockMenuEl.innerHTML = originalHTML;
  }else {
    blockMenuEl.innerHTML = '';
    return arr.forEach(res => {
      const result = renderBlock(res);
      blockMenuEl.appendChild(result);
    })
  }
}
```

Basically what the code above means is that when I deleted all the key word in the search box (which would make the filtered array to be the same as the original array `blocks`), I want to display all the items from the original display state to the screen.

Here I made a copy of the `blockMenuEl` with the `originalHTML` element. 2 questions:
*1) Since the DOM elements are stored by reference, why is it that when I make `blockMenuEl.innerHTML = '';`, the content of the `originalHTML` element doesn't change?
2) Is there a different way to copy the original element? Just wondering if there is any kind of drawback when I do it my way.*

Complete code:

```js
/*
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fUBeQtBFC962aIztTb5TvvnetmRNL2J0IJ9ToSdmrvs/edit#heading=h.b98xc82r9k1v


*/

const blocks = [
  {
    label: 'Burger',
    categoryId: 'burgers',
    categoryLabel: 'Burgers',
    tags: [ 'burger', 'lettuce', 'tomato' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Cheese Burger',
    categoryId: 'burgers',
    categoryLabel: 'Burgers',
    tags: [ 'cheese', 'burger', 'lettuce', 'tomato' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Veggie Burger',
    categoryId: 'burgers',
    categoryLabel: 'Burgers',
    tags: [ 'vegetable', 'burger', 'lettuce', 'tomato' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Fancy Burger',
    categoryId: 'burgers',
    categoryLabel: 'Burgers',
    tags: [ 'cheese', 'burger', 'lettuce', 'tomato', 'fancy sauce' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Cheese Fries',
    categoryId: 'fries',
    categoryLabel: 'Fries',
    tags: [ 'fries', 'cheese', 'potato', 'fried' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Shake',
    categoryId: 'dessert',
    categoryLabel: 'Dessert',
    tags: [ 'shake', 'milk', 'chocolate', 'strawberry', 'frozen', 'dessert', 'sweet' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Tots',
    categoryId: 'fries',
    categoryLabel: 'Fries',
    tags: [ 'fries', 'potato', 'fried', 'tater' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Kombucha',
    categoryId: 'drinks',
    categoryLabel: 'Drinks',
    tags: [ 'fermented', 'draft' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Hot Dog',
    categoryId: 'dog',
    categoryLabel: 'Hot Dogs',
    tags: [ 'relish', 'onion', 'cheese sauce', 'chopped bacon' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Fries',
    categoryId: 'fries',
    categoryLabel: 'Fries',
    tags: [ 'fries', 'cheese', 'potato', 'fried' ]
  }, {
    label: 'Tee Shirt',
    categoryId: 'merchandise',
    categoryLabel: 'Merchandise',
    tags: [ 'apparel' ]
  }
];

const PLACEHOLDER_SRC = 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/design-n-code/100/272127c4-8d19-4bd3-bd22-2b75ce94ccb4-512.png';

const blockMenuEl = document.getElementById('block-menu');

const renderBlock = (block) => {
  const { label } = block;
  const blockEl = document.createElement('div');
  const iconEl = document.createElement('img');
  const textEl = document.createElement('p');

  blockEl.classList.add('block');
  textEl.innerText = label;
  iconEl.classList.add('icon');
  iconEl.setAttribute('src', PLACEHOLDER_SRC);

  blockEl.appendChild(iconEl);
  blockEl.appendChild(textEl);
  return blockEl;
};

blocks.forEach((block) => blockMenuEl.appendChild(renderBlock(block)));

/*
grouping:
When getting all the categories, create a block. Add style to that block

*/
const grouping = (blockMenuEl) => {
  // get the categoryLabel
  const results = groupItemByCategories(blocks);
  
  // display them
  // displayAccordingToCategories(results);
  return results;
}

/*
get all the items according to 1 category
call the display function:
+) blockMenuEl.innerHTML = ''
+) take the category
+) create a new div for each item
+) blockMenuEl.appendChild(eachblock)

*/
// const groupItemByCategories = (arr) => {
//   // get all the items name
  
//   /*
//   I could do the below by doing .map to get all the categoryLabel name
//   Then chain map and filter  
//   */
//   blockMenuEl.innerHTML = '';
//   const cateArr = arr.map(item => item.categoryLabel);
//   cateArr.forEach(cate => {
//     const filteredArr = arr.filter(arr => arr.categoryLabel === cate);
//     displayAccordingToCategories(filteredArr, cate);
//   }) 
// }

const groupItemByCategories = (arr) => {
  // group items by categoryLabel
  const categ = {};
  blockMenuEl.innerHTML = '';
  
  for(let item of arr) {
    if(!(item.categoryLabel in categ)) {
      categ[item.categoryLabel] = [item];
    } else {
      categ[item.categoryLabel].push(item)
    }
  }
  
  console.log(categ)
  // display them
  for(let c in categ) {
    displayAccordingToCategories(categ[c], c);
  }
}

const displayAccordingToCategories = (filteredArr, cate) => {
  console.log(filteredArr, 'filteredArr')
  console.log(cate, 'cate');
  const categoryDiv = document.createElement('div');
  categoryDiv.textContent = cate;
  categoryDiv.classList.add('categoryName');
  
  const allItems = document.createElement('div');
  allItems.classList.add('allItems');
  filteredArr.forEach(item => {
    const itemDiv = renderBlock(item);
    allItems.appendChild(itemDiv);
  })
  
  // categoryDiv.appendChild(allItems);
  blockMenuEl.appendChild(categoryDiv);
  blockMenuEl.appendChild(allItems);
}

grouping(blockMenuEl);

/*
search function

*/
const originalHTML = blockMenuEl.innerHTML;
const clone = blockMenuEl.cloneNode(true);
console.log(originalHTML, 'clone')

const searchEle = (e) => {
  // filter
  const received = e.target.value;
  const key = received.toLowerCase();
  const filteredResults = filterEle(key);
  
  // put res on the page
  display(filteredResults);
}

const filterEle = (key) => {
  const store = blocks.filter(block => {
    const newLabel = block.label.toLowerCase();
    const newCatLabel = block.categoryLabel.toLowerCase();
    return newLabel.includes(key) || newCatLabel.includes(key) || block.tags.some(tag => tag.includes(key));
  })
  return store;
}

const display = (arr) => {
  // this works but why
  // can't do arr.length = 0 because filteredResults will never be 0
  if(arr.length === blocks.length) {
    blockMenuEl.innerHTML = originalHTML;
  }else {
    // why does this work
    // because it clears the html so I can attach something on to it
    blockMenuEl.innerHTML = '';
    return arr.forEach(res => {
      const result = renderBlock(res);
      blockMenuEl.appendChild(result);
    })
  }
}


const search = document.querySelector('#search');
// figure out how to use arrow function here
search.addEventListener('keyup', searchEle);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, input {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}


.block-selector {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 40px;
/*   height: 500px; */
  width: 400px;
  background: #fcfcfc;
/*   border: 1px solid #E8E8E8; */
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.block-selector .search {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
}

.block-selector .search input {
  padding: 11px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  line-height: 28px;
  width: 100%;
}

.block-selector .search input::placeholder {
  color: silver;
}

.block-selector .icon {
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
}

#block-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.categoryName {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.allItems {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
/*   justify-content: flex-start; */
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-selector">
  <div class="search">
    <input id="search" placeholder="Search Content Blocks" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>
  <div id="block-menu"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Since the DOM elements are stored by reference, why is it that when I make blockMenuEl.innerHTML = '';, the content of the originalHTML element doesn't change?

Because you are not copying a DOM element. When you say:

```
const originalHTML = blockMenuEl.innerHTML;
```

you are not assigning a DOM element to `originalHTML`, but just its innerHTML, which is a string.  And strings are not passed by reference.
So when you later change the element content, `originalHTML` does not get affected.

To answer your second question, if the code does what you are expecting it to do, I don't see anything wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

const variables can't be changed after assigned for this you must use var instead of const